# Viewport Checker - jQuery run loop once

Tags: jquery, viewport

I am using viewport checker and I want the animation to only run once, so far I have the following:-

```
jQuery('#style-wrapper').viewportChecker({
    callbackFunction: function(elem) {
        var flag = true;
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage .work-description').html('Different');
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage .work-description').css( "font-weight", "700" );
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage #style-wrapper').css( "background", "#7ec4bf");
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage #style-wrapper').css( "color", "#14143a");
        },1000);
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage .work-description').html('Distinct');
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage .work-description').css( "font-weight", "900" );
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage #style-wrapper').css( "background", "#14143a");
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage #style-wrapper').css( "color", "#FFFFFF");
        },2000);
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage .work-description').html('People');
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage #style-wrapper').css( "background", "#b0a893");
        },3000);
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage .work-description').html('Want');
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage .work-description').css( "font-weight", "900" );
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage .work-description').css( "font-size", "54px" );
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage #style-wrapper').css( "background", "#39779f");
            jQuery('.page-template-template-homepage #style-wrapper').css( "color", "#14143a");
        },4000);
        if (flag) {
            interval = setInterval(function(){
                flag = false;
            },5000);
        }
    }
});
```

but for some reason it keeps looping over and over again (and for some unknown reason, when it loops the second time it starts going in a different sequence).

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe something like $('#style-wrapper').one().viewportChecker({..});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) needs to be set to a variable in order to properly clear. Here is a quick [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/o49a256g/) I made to explain.

```
var myInterval;

$('button[name="start"]').click(function(){
    myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        $('body div').prepend('Oh Hai! ');
    });
});

$('button[name="end"]').click(function(){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```

As a side note, can I ask why you are creating an interval/loop if you only want it to be called once?

Try this:

```
if (flag) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

**Edit:**

So I was thinking initially you could use the `animate()` method to accomplish this through its callbacks, but then I realized half of the styles you are trying to change don't accept animation without plugins. What I came up with gives you 4 stages of css style/animation options. Each stage is nested within the `animate()` method's callback. It will change the text string through the `html()` method, and adjust any style changes you have through the `css()` or `animate()` methods. The timings are stored within the anim object and can easily be adjusted. Obviously you will still need to do some work to modify this a bit to fit your exact needs, but hopefully this gets you started!

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/qcs8c7uL/)

```
var anim = {
    config: {
        slideDelay: 1000,   // Each step will take 1 second
        intervalDelay: 8000 // The entire loop will wait 8 seconds between iterations
    },
    run: function(selector){ 
        console.log('test');
        $('.selector').html('Different').css({ // Change any CSS Components (Stage1)
            'background'    : '#7ec4bf',
            'color'         : '#14143a',
            'font-size'     : '20px'
        }).animate({ // Option to animate components (Stage1)
            'font-weight'   : 400
        }, anim.config.slideDelay, function(){
            $('.selector').html('Distinct').css({ // Change any CSS Components (Stage2)
                'background'    : '#14143a',
                'color'         : '#FFFFFF',
                'font-size'     : '10px'
            }).animate({ // Option to animate components (Stage2)
                'font-weight'   : 600
            }, anim.config.slideDelay, function(){
                $('.selector').html('People').css({ // Change any CSS Components (Stage3)
                    'background'    : '#b0a893'
                }).animate({ // Option to animate components (Stage3)
                    'font-weight'   : 900
                }, anim.config.slideDelay, function(){
                    $('.selector').html('Want').css({ // Change any CSS Components (Stage4)
                        'background'    : '#39779f',
                        'color'         : '#14143a',
                        'font-size'     : '30px'
                    }).animate({ // Option to animate components (Stage4)
                        'font-weight'   : 100
                    }, anim.config.slideDelay);
                });
            });
        });
    }
};

var test = setInterval(anim.run, anim.config.intervalDelay);
```

Comment: To be honest @wrxsti, I don't even know why it is looping in the first place

Comment: Do you not want loops, and just to have the effect happen a singular time?

Comment: What I want is for it to loop, pause on the last interval for say 5 seconds, then loop again but in the correct order

Comment: Well there are a few things fundamentally wrong with your script, but if you can elaborate on your question with as much detail as possible I'm sure we can come up with a much more suitable solution. What is the end goal of what you are trying to accomplish? Are we just trying to change some css?

Comment: Actually I think I've figured out what you are trying to do. Give me a few, and I think I can figure something out. In the meantime if you still want to elaborate feel free lol :)

Comment: I'm sure you've figured it out, but yeah, it's one circle with some text inside. Every second the text, background color, font-size is changing until it reaches the last interval where it should hold for 5 seconds, then run the loop again :)

Comment: @nsilva Updated the answer, it should get you headed in the right direction hopefully!

Comment: Your a star @wrxsti - thank you very much for this :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!